# Retain dynamically created DropDown list's selected value on event window.history.back()- JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, drop-down-menu

Can use the below question as a reference to explain the context:
[Populate one dropdown based on selection in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686735/populate-one-dropdown-based-on-selection-in-another/5687040#5687040)

On my page; after selecting the proper values from the dropdown lists and filling up a few text fields, the user submits the form.

The next page is for the confirmation, that asks the user whether he/she wants to edit the form.The edit button just takes back the user to the previous page (window.history.back()).

Now the problem is, every field on the page has retained the value that was filled by the user. Except the second dropdown list (dependent dropdown list).

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Without the context of your specific code, it's hard to answer well, but you should look into using the [window.sessionStorage or window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) to temporarily store data for persistence between pages in javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the reference Will. In my context once the user submits the page. They are taken to a confirmation page,  where they have an option to go back and edit (window.history.back()) the form. and when I click on Edit. Everything on the page retains except the dependent DropDown list's value.