# How to retain the dropdown values after selection

Tags: jquery, html

The below code is set to select 2 dropdown values on the page, which works fine, however, since the page refreshed even when 1st dropdown is selected, the dropdpwn values are not retained.

How do i retain the dropdown values ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.boxy').hide();
  var drop1Value = '';
  var drop2Value = '';
  var cntyS = getUrlVars()['cntry'];
  var piS = getUrlVars()['PI'];
  $("#drop1").on("change", function() {
    var drop1Value = $('#drop1').val();

    if (drop1Value == "") {
      $('#content').hide();
    } else {
      drop1Value = $('#drop1').val();
    }

    var bURL = document.location.origin + document.location.pathname + '?cntry=' + drop1Value + '&PI=' + piS;
    window.location.href = bURL;
  });

  $("#drop2").on("change", function() {
    var drop2Value = $('#drop2').val();

    if (drop2Value == "") {
      $('#content').hide();
    } else {
      drop2Value = $('#drop2').val();
    }

    var bURL = document.location.origin + document.location.pathname + '?cntry=' + cntyS + '&PI=' + drop2Value;
    window.location.href = bURL;
  });
});

function getUrlVars() {
  var vars = [],
    hash;
  var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
  for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars.push(hash[0]);
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
  }
  return vars;
}
```

Comment: Similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139788/with-javascript-keep-selected-value-in-dropdown-list

Comment: can you help me on the above code...

Answer (score 0):

jQuery supports method chaining. You can utilize that to set the value like this:

```
$('myselector').on('...', function () {}).val(myValue)
```

In your case, this is the correct code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.boxy').hide();
  var drop1Value = '';
  var drop2Value = '';
  var cntyS = getUrlVars()['cntry'];
  var piS = getUrlVars()['PI'];
  $("#drop1").on("change", function() {
    var drop1Value = $('#drop1').val();

    if (drop1Value == "") {
      $('#content').hide();
    } else {
      drop1Value = $('#drop1').val();
    }

    var bURL = document.location.origin + document.location.pathname + '?cntry=' + drop1Value + '&PI=' + piS;
    window.location.href = bURL;
  }).children('[value="'+cntyS+'"]').prop('selected', true);

  $("#drop2").on("change", function() {
    var drop2Value = $('#drop2').val();

    if (drop2Value == "") {
      $('#content').hide();
    } else {
      drop2Value = $('#drop2').val();
    }

    var bURL = document.location.origin + document.location.pathname + '?cntry=' + cntyS + '&PI=' + drop2Value;
    window.location.href = bURL;
  }).children('[value="'+piS+'"]').prop('selected', true);
});

function getUrlVars() {
  var vars = [],
    hash;
  var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
  for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars.push(hash[0]);
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
  }
  return vars;
}
```

Comment: another question..
The webpage brings "Pricing Inventory: IN - AC" when India & AC is selected in drop1 & drop2.. I want IN to show as India... is that possible..

'<select id="drop1">
    <option value="">---Select Country---</option>
    <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
    <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
    <option value="CN">China</option>'

however, i dont want to change the value from CN to China...