# Which one is more efficient: cookie or sql connection?

Tags: sql, .net-core, cookies

I am currently working on a web application for .net Core and I will need to access a small piece of data on every move the user makes. And I was wondering which one uses more time to get the data and if there is a significant difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to store small UI user preferences in web app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534535/best-way-to-store-small-ui-user-preferences-in-web-app)

Comment: this is not a duplicate, I rephrased the question a little to make it clearer.

Comment: If it's the same data every time, you can simply set a session variable.

Comment: The decision depends on several factors: if you have millions of concurrent users you should minimise server resources and go for client storage where possible. But client storage is under the user's control, who can wipe it out any time, or could even tamper with it, just like with client scripts.