# Collapsing DIV Tag

Tags: javascript, java, html, tags

i'm trying to create a collapse and expand a div.
At this moment i've implemented this code:

```
<a id="displayText" data-toggle="collapse" data target="#${facetData.code}"> push here </a>

<div id="${facetData.code}" class="facet__values js-facet-values js-facet-form collapse" > this will disappear    </div>
```

div is being correctly collapsed and expanded, but when i refresh the page, the divs(i've more then one) that i've expanded are being collapsed (as default status)

i would like to keep the open divs also after the page is refreshed..
i'm new with jsp and java tag lib

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Marco

Comment: You are going to have to set cookies on user preferences, then when the page loads get cookie data and update DIVs visibility

Comment: Hi Sterling Thanks for your reply...sorry but i'm new in web programming..do you have a snippet about this?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this gets you in the **right direction**:
[Best way to store small UI user preferences in web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534535/best-way-to-store-small-ui-user-preferences-in-web-app)

```
// add variable to HTML5 local storage, when div visibility on change
...{
      // expand or close div | update preference in local storage
      localStorage.setItem('divID', 'show'); // or set 'hide'
}
```

When the page loads, access local storage and update DIVs

```
var data = localStorage.getItem('divID');
if(data != 'show') {
    getElementById('divID').style.display = "none";
}
```