# Using various Chrome site data storage options?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, web-applications, local-storage

I was looking at my stored cookies in Chrome for the first time by looking at chrome://settings/siteData.  In addition to cookies, I noticed various other storage types - cache storage, database storage, local storage, service workers, etc.  For example:

[image: Chrome storage example]

I am familiar with cookies and local storage and how to store to them from JavaScript, but not the others.  My  questions:

1. Where do the others come from, i.e., how do they get read/written/deleted from JavaScript, for example?
2. What are specific advantages of the local storage options, for example, are some better designed for storing information securely?
3. Which of these are well-suited for storing user UI preferences?  (I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534535/best-way-to-store-small-ui-user-preferences-in-web-app) from 2011.)
4. Which of these are "standard" and which are specific to Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Google has a [web storage overview page](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/) on its developer site that answers some of these questions.  In particular, it sorta answers question (4) by indicating the current browser support (as of 20 June 2019):

```
File system     52%
Local Storage   93%
Session Storage 93%
Cookies        100%
WebSQL          77%
Cache           60%
IndexedDB       83%
cloud storage  100%
```